# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference fatal error

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to pass JSON Data to listview with an adapter. Now I got an error in logcat:

```
09-18 17:03:46.787 6429-6429/ir.homa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: ir.homa, PID: 6429
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.homa/ir.homa.HotelDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                       at ir.homa.HotelDetail.onCreate(HotelDetail.java:43)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

this is my adapter:

```
 package ir.homa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 9/17/2016.
 */
public class RoomTypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomType> {
    public RoomTypeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomType> roomType) {
        super(context,0, roomType);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position , View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent ){
        RoomType roomType = getItem(position);
        if (ConvertView == null) {

            ConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_type, parent, false);
        }
        TextView typeItem = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.itemRoomType);
        typeItem.setText(roomType.RoomType);
        return ConvertView;
    }



}
```

this is my class which contains variables:

```
package ir.homa;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 9/17/2016.
 */
public class RoomType {
    String RoomType;
    String id;
    public void setRoomType(JSONObject object) {
        try {
            this.RoomType = object.getString("description");
            this.id = object.getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my MainActivity:

```
package ir.homa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 9/4/2016.
 */
public class HotelDetail extends Activity {


    // json array response url
    private String urlJsonArry = "http://homa.qadamgahi.ir/bandar_result.json";
    private static String TAG = HotelDetail.class.getSimpleName();


    ArrayList<RoomType> typeList;
    RoomTypeAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        typeList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RoomTypeAdapter(this, typeList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        makeJsonObjectRequest();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        /*
      ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
      See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
        GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to make json object request where json response starts wtih {
     * */
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonArry, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object

                RoomType o = new RoomType();

                try {

                    for (int i = 0 ; i < typeList.size() ; i++)
                    {


                        RoomType add = new RoomType();
                        add.id = response.getString("id");
                        add.RoomType = response.getString("description");
                        typeList.add(add);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

}
```

please show me how can I populate json data with listview and what is this problem ?!

Comment: how you are setting adapter to your `view` , you have posted adapter twice , post code where you are setting adapter

Comment: this is `NullPointerException` which means either you haven't initialized your view and you are trying to populate data in it. or that view does not exist within your Layout XML file. or you may have misspelled it.

Comment: Sorry... I added my MainActivity.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `setContentView()` method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContetntView(R.layout.main_activity);
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: to answer the question, i didn't noticed that you have revised your answer.